# How do I delete an item from a ListView without deleting it from the database?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have implemented a snackbar in my app that has an Undo button to undo the delete. Currently how it works is, when the user deletes an item, I keep a cursor with the item by performing a query from the database, the item is then deleted from the database and the list is updated via `notifyChange()`. When the user taps on the Undo button on the snackbar, I extract the content from the saved cursor, create a new ContentValue and insert it into the database, again calling `notifyChange()` to update the list.
I dont like this approach. There is one too many database operation.
Is there any way I can just remove/hide an item from the ListView and only delete the item when the snackbar goes away?
I tried setting the visibility to GONE or INVISIBLE but that leaves a blank space in the middle of the ListView.
I am using a CursorAdapter to populate the ListView. There is a 3 dot menu on each list item that shows a delete option.
Here is my current CursorAdapter code

```
public class ProductCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = ProductCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
protected ContentResolver contentResolver;

public ProductCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    super(context, c);
    this.contentResolver = contentResolver;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    TextView supplier = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.supplier);

    final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductEntry._ID));

    ImageView threeDotMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.three_dot_menu);
    threeDotMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_item_context_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.context_delete_product:
                            //the uri of the product we're deleting
                            Uri currentProductUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ProductEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
                            //What to extract from the database
                            String[] projection = {
                                    ProductEntry._ID,
                                    ProductEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
                                    ProductEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY,
                                    ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRICE,
                                    ProductEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER,
                                    ProductEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE
                            };
                            //retrieve the product from the database before deleting in case
                            //we need to restore it later
                            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(currentProductUri,
                                    projection,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null);
                            cursor.moveToFirst();
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout), "Product Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.setAction("Undo", new MyUndoListener(cursor));
                            snackbar.show();
                            contentResolver.delete(currentProductUri, null, null);
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });


    . . .


}

public class MyUndoListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    Cursor cursor = null;

    public MyUndoListener(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        contentResolver.insert(ProductEntry.CONTENT_URI, extractFromCursor(cursor));
    }

    private ContentValues extractFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {

        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductEntry._ID));

        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductEntry.COLUMN_NAME));

        int quantity = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY));

        int price = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRICE));

        String supplier = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER));

        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE));
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
        value.put(ProductEntry._ID, id);
        value.put(ProductEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
        value.put(ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRICE, price);
        value.put(ProductEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY, quantity);
        value.put(ProductEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER, supplier);
        value.put(ProductEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE, image);
        cursor.close();
        return value;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: add one column of a boolean type named "deleted" in the table and put true if deleted otherwise false and display only those record whose deleted value is false.

Answer (score 0):

Well Nishan, For This make Arraylist of database values and then bind a listview. whenever you want to delete one item (Not from your database) then make a copy of arraylist without that item and again bind the listview.

Thus you have your database remains same and you can use it again in case of undo.
So what item you want to delete , bind a new arraylist from orignal arraylst without that item and use it.

Comment: `CursorAdapter` does  not works that way. It relies on database cursor instead of a list.